# pandas cleaning 1+1 values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that has the following data

```
column
------
1+1
2+3
4+5
```

How do I get pandas to sum these values so that the out put is 2,5,9 instead of the above?

Many thanks

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: Is the data type of your column `str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You column obviously contains strings, so, you must somehow evaluate them. Use `pd.eval` function. Eg

```py
frame['column'].apply(pd.eval)
```

> If interested in performance, probably use an alternative method, like `ast.literal_eval`. Thanks to user @`Serge Ballesta` for mentioning

Comment: I would not use `pd.eval` here. The Pandas documentation says *You should not use eval() for simple expressions or for expressions involving small DataFrames. In fact, eval() is many orders of magnitude slower for smaller expressions/objects than plain ol’ Python. A good rule of thumb is to only use eval() when you have a DataFrame with more than 10,000 rows.*. So I would stick to `frame['column'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: @SergeBallesta: you are correct about performance, but from the question it seems the OP seems to be just starting out with pandas, so I thought it would be better to focus on the data types

Comment: No problem for me. I just thought interesting to note it for future readers because I have just discovered the point ;-)